# How to dynamically format a templated string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a CSV file with some fields such as `first_name`, `last_name`, etc and a string as follows.

```
Hi {first_name} {last_name}, ...
```

Note that the keys can change but they will always be a subset of the fields in the CSV.

How can I use string formatting to replace the value in the string from CSV?

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and your expected output? I'm not really clear on what you're after as your question stands right now

Comment: Hi, checkout the answer by @rankie567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
input = 'Hi {first_name} {last_name}'
# Assuming you have a dict of your variables
data = {
    'first_name': 'John',
    'last_name': 'Doe',
}
output = input.format(**data) # Hi John Doe
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work! I didn't know you could use formatting this way by unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

let's say that you import a dataframe with pandas form a csv file. This dataframe is called people:

[people dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNtK6.png)

and a string variable like this to loop string formatting over all dataframe rows:

```
'Hi {first_name} {last_name}'
```

you can use this:

```
 [string.format(first_name = row['first_name'], last_name = row['last_name']) for index,row in people.iterrows()]
```

[code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmpqZ.png)

Comment: I can't do `first_name=row['first_name']` because `first_name` can be anything else as well.